# Scrolling on different Android versions not working the same

Tags: android, scroll

I'm developing an Android app. On my login screen, where a user enters their info, I click on a field to enter a value and the keyboard comes up so I can type. However, when it comes up, it blocks the last field so I can't see what I'm typing. I can scroll up on Android 2.1, but for any version higher than that, I can't scroll up which means I can't see the field I'm entering info in.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml in your activity then it will resize your layout so you can see it. It should work, but depends how you've got your layout arranged - you might get a weird effect!

```
<activity name="myActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
    ...
</activity>
```